# Does "docker run" actually SSH into the container?

Tags: docker, containers

If I run

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

Does it actually SSH into the container, or does it use another protocol?

Comment: No, there is no SSH involved. Docker uses a technology called namespaces to provide the isolated workspace called the container. https://docs.docker.com/engine/docker-overview/#namespaces

Comment: @oryades you should think about turning this comment in an answer IMHO.

Comment: As a side note in most cases you want to `docker run -it --rm ubuntu su -` rather than running bash. Running `su - ` simulates a full login and as a result, initialises some environment variables such as `TERM`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it uses an internal ["attach protocol"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/) via the Docker daemon.